# How to get the url of the reference attachment?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am using Microsoft Graph. When I use

```
GET /me/messages/{messageId}/attachments
```

If there is an attachment shared through OneDrive or SharePoint, the `@odata.type` will be `#microsoft.graph.referenceAttachment`. And the size is very small because it is not real file.

```
 {
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.referenceAttachment",
  "id": "AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgBGAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhBwCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAAAEMAACpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAEBiQutAAABEgAQAMqgyfrokPFCrRfUa2mrxxM=",
  "name": "word.docx",
  "contentType": null,
  "size": 4601,
  "isInline": false
}
```

Is there any way to get the actual url of this attachment that can be opened in the browser? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The v1.0 edition has *very* limited support for [`referenceAttachment`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/referenceattachment). And by that I mean, there isn't much you can do with them beyond acknowledging one exists.

The beta edition however supports a much richer [`referenceAttachment`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/referenceattachment) object. When I come across a `referenceAttachment`, I make the call to retrieve the attachment using the beta endpoint which *does* have links to the actual file:

```
{
  "contentType": "string",
  "id": "string (identifier)",
  "isFolder": true,
  "isInline": true,
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "name": "string",
  "permission": "string",
  "previewUrl": "string",
  "providerType": "string",
  "size": 1024,
  "sourceUrl": "string",
  "thumbnailUrl": "string"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are after is `sourceUrl` property of [`referenceAttachment` resource](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/referenceattachment):

> URL to get the attachment content. If this is a URL to a folder, then
>   for the folder to be displayed correctly in Outlook or Outlook on the
>   web, set isFolder to true. Required.

but this property is not available for `v1.0` API version, `beta` endpoint needs to be utilized instead:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/{message-id}/attachments/{arrachement-id}
```